# How a force that is always perpendicular to velocity can change the kinetic energy when another force is acting oppposite to velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity

When a satellite is revolving around a planet with an orbital velocity in presence of air resistance, the satellite's Kinetic Energy keeps on increasing as it falls down. The resistive force is trying to decrease the speed and the gravitational force cannot change the speed (or Kinetic Energy) as it's perpendicular to the velocity. Or, am I wrong and gravity can actually change K.E. even if it's always perpendicular to velocity. In the Free Body Diagram, I see no force acting along the velocity that can increase the speed of the satellite.

Answer (score 1):

> the gravitational force cannot change the speed (or Kinetic Energy) as
> it's perpendicular to the velocity.

The gravitational acceleration is always radial, and the velocity can be orthogonal to it in a given time. But in general it doesn't stay orthogonal, unless the velocity is exactly $V = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{R}}$.

The general bound orbit is an ellipse, where the velocity is not perpendicular to the radial direction.

In your case, the air drag reduces the modulus of the velocity, and even if that equality holds at time $t$, it doesn't hold in $t+\delta t$.